# Create and distribute printers

Tags: sharing, printing, macos

Is there a way to create a printer on a machine. Then bundle up the Printer bundle and create an installer out of it for multiple users at a location. To avoid having to explain to each user how to install a network printer?

This is one of those enterprise issues.
(10.6 specifically... at least for the next month)

Comment: Do you have MacOS X Server and are you part of that server's Open Directory?

Comment: I have an installation of OSX Server with an OD that is for the machines, there is also a separate AD which the machines point to as well. The Server itself is in the AD. Our AD can't handle the OD Mac extensions... too old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Macs are part of the OS X Server's OD, then you can use Workgroup Manager to assign printers to either Groups of users or Groups of Machines.

If you want to manage the drivers and the detailed printer settings, this [link](http://www.blueboxmoon.com/wordpress/?p=249) might help.